# Change UIWebView's color while loading content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, htmltext, textrenderer

I have a UIWebView in my app that shows some html-formatted text (loaded from a .plist file from my bundle). The UIWebView takes about 1 second to render the text on the screen and during that second the whole UIWebView is white. I have tried setting the backgronud color of the view to `clear` or `black` but that did not do anything. I also tried using the delegate methods to show the UIWebView only when it `didLoadContent` but that method is never called since there us no request involved, I'm only rendering an html string there.

Is there a way to show nothing until the view is rendered?

If not, is there another way to render html-text on an iPhone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my mind:
Set the UIWebView's `hidden` property to YES, display something call a selector to change the hidden property to NO in 2-3 seconds.

BTW do you mean you're loading a local HTML file? Or is the delay created by downloading the file?

~ Natanavra.

Comment: Nothing is loaded. The html is written in an `NSString` like `@"<html><body>...</body></html>"`.

The selector approach will not work for me, because this html text is what is displayed while the app loads. So it stays on the screen only for a few seconds. Thus:

1. I want it to appear as soon as it is loaded.
2. I don't want a selector to fire too late when my whole UIViewController has been de-allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You said this HTML was loaded and presented "while app loads" which I guess means starting up instead of loading some other data from somewhere? I'm also guessing the HTML is fully static hardcoded data, since you load it "offline" from .plist...

**Suggestion**: why don't you take a screenshot of the ready-rendered page, save that inside your app and display during app startup? Should be faster.

Comment: It's offline data but it has to be dynamic. I have 20 different HTMLs in a plist and I want to render a random one every time. What I did in the end, was have 20 images (the rendered thing) and load those instead (so, what you suggested above more or less)...

Answer (score 0):

I handle this in my app with a javascript variable that I check with a NSTimer that is fired every 0.5 seconds... I leave the view hidden until that variable is set...